# How can I eliminate odor from exterior paint used indoors?

Tags: paint, exterior, smell

I painted my inner walls with exterior plastic paint by mistake. It had a very foul odor when summer came. Painted 3 times and still smells

Smell is terrible in summer months especially when opening the windows. I had 4 layers of plastic (very low VOCs) and still during summer months the wall smell terribly.

Comment: How long ago did you paint?  Opening windows should usually reduce smells coming from indoor surfaces, so are you sure it is the paint and not something else.

Comment: Strip the paint back to remove that outdoor paint, as it will still emit voc's as it is designed to resist UV, temperature swings etc.

Comment: You perhaps need to hone your definitions. What's 'plastic paint?' Define 'foul', which is more commonly used to describe something putrid. I would expect a paint to have, in the broadest terms, a 'chemical' smell. There's not really much detail here we can work on, except to say, 'get rid of whatever smells & start over'.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does "plastic" paint mean "acrylic"? Perhaps that was the result of a machine translation of the word "acrylic".

Answer (score 3):

Exterior paint doesn't care which side of the wall it's on.  It shouldn't stink.

Stink is usually caused by *old* paint that has gone rancid because of mold or fungus growth, because modern paint isn't toxic enough to suppress mold growth.  You don't save any money using old paint.  And unfortunately when they crack the can to mix a custom color, that breaks the seal.

Unfortunately, in the experience of most people that **this cannot be "sealed up"** - many have tried using sealers or bleach treatments, never works.  After they've tried sealers and found they didn't work, the job of removing the paint is *much harder*.

The only option is to entirely remove it - fortunately fresh latex paint is fairly fragile. Blast a humidifier in that room continuously so it doesn't harden any further, and then tear it off the walls by wetting it and going to town with harsh scrub brushes, paint stripper, whatever it takes. Lots of physical labor, but sorry, no one is able to seal it.